# Font color by classes on li are not rendered until unfocus in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I have a very strange problem in jQuery/CSS an I'm not sure what's is going wrong here. Consider this minimal example:

```
#list li {
    color:#3c6174;
    cursor:pointer;
}

#list li.active {
    color:red;
}

<ul id="list">
    <li class="active"></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>

$buttons = $("#list li");
$buttons.click(function() {
    $buttons.removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

View the code ([fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/RrP5x/4/)) in Chrome and click on one of the list buttons. Nothing happens. But, if you unfocus the window, it suddenly activates the class and the red color is rendered.

It seems to work fine in Firefox how it's supposed to be: as soon as a list item is clicked, it's color is switched to red and the others are blue again.

Viewing the DOM shows that the class is removed and added on the clicked element without any sort of delay, so I don't understand why it is not rendered immediately.

What is happening here?

PS: Using `33.0.1750.146 m` on Windows Prof x64

Comment: Happens immediately for me, Chrome v26 on Linux.

Comment: Weird, but I don't get the update very easily on Chrome v33 on Windows at all. It's not immediate, and even just focus/unfocus doesn't do it, I have to do things like minimize/restore.

Comment: Working perfectly fine. http://jsfiddle.net/RrP5x/5/

Comment: @MuthukannanKanniappan Try without text instead. Then it only updates when you switch chrome tabs or unfocus/refocus window.

Comment: Worth [reporting to the Chromium team](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list) if it's not already a known issue. (Could well be WebKit rather than Chrome, might be worth checking that first.)

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=348967

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the new version of Chrome considers that nothing needs to be redrawn if tags are empty and the only change is the class is the text color. Put a letter inside every li element and it works.
Or:
Place border:1px solid red; inside the CSS rule. It works because it has to do with the box properties of the element.

Comment: Perfect. I added `&nbsp;` into the elements and it works fine now. Thanks a bunch